# Can use Babel with mixed vanilla + jquery code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6, babeljs

What happens if I transpile some vanilla ES6 code that also contains some jquery code? I'd like to start learning ES6 but have a lot of jquery and ES5 code.

NOTE: I don't need to convert jquery to vanilla (so I don't need to use babel's jquery transpile plugins); I just want to have ES6 converted to ES5, but my code for now would include mixed ES6+jquery.

So what would happen when running Babel on that code? Is it possible? Drawbacks? Known bugs?

Comment: Writing stuff in jQuery _is_ ES6 code (unless you include ESNext things). Not sure why people keep thinking jQuery is any sort of special, it's just a standard library like a lot of others out there.

Comment: i believe that if you will not use babel jquery plugin then babel will not transpile jquery to vanila

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried to compile a js file that's using jquery libraries. It won't compile properly. So the answer is no. At least not out of the box (didn't play with options).

Comment: A JS file using jQuery should compile just fine using Babel. What was the code? What did you try? What was the error?